# How can I change its color?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

How can I make any word I write it in

```
 <a href=""></a>
```

it's color black ?
Every thing I write it in

```
 <a href=""></a>
```

it's color blue not black and I like to remove the line that under any word I write it in it

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this

```
.disabled-link
{
    cursor: default;              
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

<a href="" class="disabled-link"></a>
```

and if you want to make it **unclickable** use this CSS line

```
 pointer-events: none;
```